# How can I create dynamic components with Google App Scripts for Google Sites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sites

I am trying to create dynamic app script components that can be added into my site with dynamic data for each instance of the script. I tried doing parameters, but I am not sure if that's the best way to approach this. For example, I want to create an image script that be loaded with dynamic links, and inserted into google sites. I only want one image script can be loaded multiple times into the page with dynamic urls. How should I handle this? Can this be done? Thanks.

Comment: Will you be using the new Google Sites or the Classic Sites?  See the disclaimer on this page: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page

Comment: I am using the classic Sites.

Comment: Try to create a [mcve] and add the code to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version creates scrolling images display or a slide show.  And it creates the image tags in an otherwise empty div.  You can add as many images to column A  of your spreadsheet and the script will do the rest.

image.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="myimages"></div>
  <div id="slideshow" style="display:none;">
    <img id="slide" src="" width="450"/>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Start Slide Show" onClick="startShow();" />
  <input type="button" value="Stop Show" onClick="stopShow();" />
  <div id="resp" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Response</h1>
    <p>Your data has been received.</p>
  </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var nextslide=0;
      var myslides='';
      var mytimer;
      $(function() {
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(setURL)
          .getURL();
      });
      function setURL(urlA)
      {
        for(var i=0;i<urlA.length;i++)
        {
          var s='img' + Number(i+1);
          var s1= '#img' + Number(i+1);
          $('#myimages').append('<img id="' + s + '" src="' + urlA[i] + '" />');
          $(s1).attr('height','450');
        }
        myslides=urlA;
      }
      
      function startShow()
      {
        $('#myimages').css('display','none');
        $('#slideshow').css('display','block');
        showSlide();
      }
       
      function showSlide()
      {
        document.getElementById('slide').src=myslides[nextslide];
        if(++nextslide > myslides.length-1)
        {
            nextslide=0;
        }
        mytimer=window.setTimeout(showSlide,5000);
      }
     
       function stopShow()
       {
         window.clearTimeout(mytimer);
         $('#myimages').css('display','block');
        $('#slideshow').css('display','none');
         
       }
       
      function loadTxt(from,to)
      {
          document.getElementById(to).value = document.getElementById(from).value;
      }
      
     console.log('My Code');
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs

```
function doGet()
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('image');
  return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
  
}

function getData(a)
{
  var ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-6", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
  a.push(ts);
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SS_ID')
  ss.getSheetByName('Form Data').appendRow(a);
  return true;
}

function getURL()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SS_ID');
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('imgURLs');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var urlA=[];
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    urlA.push(rngA[i][0]);
  }
  return urlA;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example:

image.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="data">
    <br /><img id="img1" src="" alt="img1" width="300" />
    <br /><img id="img2" src="" alt="img2" width="300" />
  </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(setURL)
          .getURL();
      });
      function setURL(urlA)
      {
         for(var i=0;i<urlA.length;i++)
         {
           var s='img' + Number(i+1);
           document.getElementById(s).src=urlA[i];
         }
      }
     console.log('My Code');
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs file:

```
function doGet()
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('image');
  return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)

}

function getURL()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('imgURLs');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var urlA=[];
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    urlA.push(rngA[i][0]);
  }
  return urlA;
}
```

This gets the image url from sheet named 'imgURLs' with the appropriate Spreadsheet ID and I'm just using column A (just using A2 and A3 right now but you can use 1 or more images. You can save is as a webapp and go to the classic sites select insert google apps and type in the web app url from the publish menu and that's it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Manage Sites -> Apps Script to embed a new script into your classic site.
2. Create a new function to build the dynamic html that you need

   ```
   function makePage() {
     var page = SitesApp.getCurrentPage();
     //create your html
     page.setHtmlContent()
   }
   ```
3. Add a doGet method that will call makePage()

   ```
   function doGet(e) {
     makePage();
   }
   ```
4. Publish your script as a web app setting the script to run as you.  Get the url to your script.
5. There are different ways to force this code to be executed from your page.  One mechanism would be to insert a call to App Script on your Sites page.  Provide the URL to your App Script web app in the gadget wizard.